# Is there a way to clear one column filter dynamically in Angular 17 - Primeng?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

**I am using angular 17 with Primeng 17**

The filter is being removed from PrimeNG table filters or whenever I try to clear the filter value for my table. Is there another way to clear the filter for a specific column?

I have the following input inside a p-columnFilter in my template:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                        @switch(column.type){
                        @case('number'){
                        <p-inputNumber inputId="integeronly" [ngModel]="value"
                            (onInput)="applyColumnFilter(column, $event.value)"
                            class="p-inputtext-sm w-full"></p-inputNumber>
                        }
                        @default {
                        <input (input)="applyColumnFilter(column, $any($event.target).value)" pInputText
                            [ngModel]="value" class="p-inputtext-sm w-full" placeholder="Search..." />
                        }
                        }
                    </ng-template>
```

Whenever I call the removeFilter Dynamically

```
removeFilter(index: number) {
    this.table?.filter('', 'attribute', FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS);
  }
```

Comment: possible to provide minimal reproducible code in a stackblitz and screenshot of expected output?